# Merge Data frames with respect to column (date) AND row (country)

Tags: r

I have the following data, as show below.

I want to merge such that the returns from DF2 (Columns "US", "CA") are included in DF1 with respect to date and Country. I know how to merge with respect to columns, but do not know how to match with the correct country.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

DF1

```
          Company Country Delt.1.arithmetic       date
2021-03-01    TSLA      CA                NA 2021-03-01
2021-03-02    TSLA      CA       -0.04452764 2021-03-02
2021-03-03    MSFT      US       -0.04842374 2021-03-03
2021-03-04    TSLA      CA       -0.04862218 2021-03-04
2021-03-05    MSFT      US       -0.03779929 2021-03-05
2021-03-08    TSLA      CA       -0.05844972 2021-03-08
```

DF2

```
     US    CA       date
 -0.02 -0.02 2021-03-01
 -0.02 -0.02 2021-03-02
 -0.02 -0.02 2021-03-03
 -0.02 -0.02 2021-03-04
 -0.02 -0.02 2021-03-05
 -0.02 -0.02 2021-03-08
```

I want:

```
          Company Country Delt.1.arithmetic       date   Return
2021-03-01    TSLA      CA                NA 2021-03-01  0,02
2021-03-02    TSLA      CA       -0.04452764 2021-03-02  0,02 
2021-03-03    MSFT      US       -0.04842374 2021-03-03  0,01
2021-03-04    TSLA      CA       -0.04862218 2021-03-04  0,01
2021-03-05    MSFT      US       -0.03779929 2021-03-05  0,02
2021-03-08    TSLA      CA       -0.05844972 2021-03-08  0,02
```

Code for sample data:

```
require(quantmod)
require(zoo)

# STOCK DATA.FRAME
TSLA <- as.data.frame(getSymbols.yahoo("TSLA", from="2021-03-01", verbose=F, auto.assign=F))
AAPL <- as.data.frame(getSymbols.yahoo("AAPL", from="2021-03-01", verbose=F, auto.assign=F))
MSFT <- as.data.frame(getSymbols.yahoo("MSFT", from="2021-03-01", verbose=F, auto.assign=F))


TSLA$Company <- c("TSLA")
AAPL$Company <- c("AAPL")
MSFT$Company <- c("MSFT")

TSLA$Country <- "CA"
AAPL$Country <- "US"
MSFT$Country <- "US"

TSLA$Return <- Delt(TSLA$TSLA.Adjusted)
AAPL$Return <- Delt(AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted)
MSFT$Return <- Delt(MSFT$MSFT.Adjusted)

colnames(TSLA) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted", "Company", "Country", "Return")
colnames(AAPL) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted", "Company","Country", "Return")
colnames(MSFT) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted", "Company","Country", "Return")

stocks <- rbind(TSLA, AAPL, MSFT)

stocks$Open <- NULL
stocks$Close <- NULL
stocks$High <- NULL
stocks$Low <- NULL
stocks$Volume <- NULL
stocks$Adjusted <- NULL

stocks$date <- row.names(stocks)

# Market returns 
date <- stocks$date
US <- sample(c(-0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, 0.15, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02), size = nrow(stocks), replace=T)
CA <- sample(c(-0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, 0.15, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02), size = nrow(stocks), replace=T)

market <- data.frame(US,CA,date)
rm(AAPL,MSFT,US,CA,TSLA, date)
```

Comment: By using `tidyr::pivot_longer` on DF2 you can create the Country column and use it for your join/merge.

Comment: It would be much appreciated if your sample data was just the output of `dput` or a call to `data.frame`.

Comment: Hmm, im not sure how that would work practically speaking. Could you show me an example? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% pivot_longer(-date, names_to = "Country", values_to = "Return"))
```

Returns:

> ```
>   Company Country Delt.1.arithmetic       date Return
> 1    TSLA      CA                NA 2021-03-01  -0.02
> 2    TSLA      CA       -0.04452764 2021-03-02  -0.02
> 3    MSFT      US       -0.04842374 2021-03-03  -0.02
> 4    TSLA      CA       -0.04862218 2021-03-04  -0.02
> 5    MSFT      US       -0.03779929 2021-03-05  -0.02
> 6    TSLA      CA       -0.05844972 2021-03-08  -0.02
> ```

I was not able to reproduce your desired output with the values you supplied (Return is all -0.02 for my data, while your desired output has also -0.01...). And since no direction for the join was specified I assumed left. Adapt it so it fits your case.

Comment: Yes, i changed some values in the display of data. Your method makes everything correct. Thank you!